# Custom Membership Provider Umbraco Issues

Tags: active-directory, umbraco

I'm looking to use a custom membership provider to authenticate Umbraco members against an Active Directory however I'm having issues with adding the additional provider into the web.config file.

When I add the extra string in to reference the AD provider all of my Umbraco macros fail with the "Error loading MacroEngine" error. Below is my string, are there any obvious problems with it?

```
<add name="MyADMembershipProvider"
type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
connectionStringName="LDAPConnection" connectionUsername="DOMAIN\USER"
connectionPassword="REMOVED" connectionProtection="None" />
```

LDAP connection string:

```
<add name="LDAPConnection" connectionString="LDAP://SERVER.DOMAIN.co.uk:389/DC=DOMAIN,DC=co,DC=uk" />
```

Thanks for any help you can offer, really at a stuck point with this!

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 6.1.1

Comment: Are you using one of the Active Directory packages or rolling your own?